# example of finite dimensional vector space having finite elements

Tags: vector-spaces

i read in examples of finite vector spaces that "set of all 2*2 matrices in Z2 is a finite vector space"..where Z2 is set of residue classes modulo 2.also it has 16 elements in it but i don't know what are the  16 elements of this vector space.so tell me about its elements please.

Comment: I will tell you one of them
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0\\
  0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
What are the rest 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four positions in the matrix, and each can have a $0$ or a $1$ - two choices for four positions $2^4=16$

Note that considering the matrices as a vector space in this way, respects matrix addition (which is just componentwise addition), and multiplication by a scalar, but says nothing about what might happen if you multiply matrices by each other.

Comment: oh yes it's really helpful..

Comment: Indeed all n by n-matrices with values in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ constitute a finite vector space with finite number of elements: a total of $m^{(n^2)}$ elements.